# resizable not working from 2nd click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

resizable not working from 2nd click can you explain me why?
In the below code, actually i am trying to add shirt and pant to the div. and when they are added, I have to resize them so i have even added resize button. Resize is working for the first time and when ever we try to add another shirt or pant. resize is not working. May i know the reason and help me out in finishing this project.

```
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Outfit Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // sets draggable the elements with id="shirt"
  $('#shirt').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',        // sets the cursor apperance
    containment: '#leftpanel'    // sets to can be dragged only within its parent
  });
  // sets draggable the paragraph inside #trousers
  $('#trousers').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: '#leftpanel'      // sets to can be dragged only within its parent
  });

  $('#btn').click(function() {
    // removes all LI with class="cls" in OL
    $('#shirt').resizable({
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: '#leftpanel'      // sets to can be dragged only within its parent
  });
  $('#trousers').resizable({
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: '#leftpanel'      // sets to can be dragged only within its parent
  });
  });
});

  var shirt;
  var pant;
  function selectshirt(src)
  {
  shirt = src;
  path = "<img src=\""+src+"\" height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\"/>";
  invisible("middlepanel");
  visible("rightpanel");

  document.getElementById("shirt").innerHTML=path;
  document.getElementById("cart").style.visibility="visible";
  }
  function selectpants(src)
  {
  pant = src;
  path = "<img class=\"pic1\" src=\""+src+"\" height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\"/>";
  document.getElementById("trousers").innerHTML=path;
  }
  function addtocart()
  {
  alert("Shirt:"+shirt+"\npant:"+pant);
  }
  function changeshirt()
  {
  visible("middlepanel");
  invisible("rightpanel");
  }
  function changepant()
  {
  visible("shirtcontainer");    
  invisible("pantcontainer");
  }
  function visible(containername)
  {
  document.getElementById(containername).style.visibility="visible";
  }
  function invisible(containername)
  {
  document.getElementById(containername).style.visibility="hidden";
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="leftpanel" style="width:800px;height:600px;border:1px solid black;">
    <div id="shirt"  style="left:0;height:300px;width:300px;"></div>
    <div id="trousers" style="left:0;height:300px;width:300px;" ></div>
</div> 
<div style="left:0;height:70%;" id="cart">
    <button  onclick="changeshirt()">Change Shirt</button>
    <button  onclick="addtocart()">Add to cart</button>
    <button id="btn">Resize</button>
</div> 
<div id="middlepanel" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:33%;overflow:auto;">
    <div id="shirtcontainer">
        <img src="images/shirts/shirt.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
    </div>
</div> 
<div id="rightpanel" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:33%;overflow:auto;">
    <div id="pantcontainer">
        <img src="images/pants/pant.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
<script>
invisible("rightpanel");
invisible("cart");
</script>
</html>
```

Please help me in this and make rezizable working from 2nd click also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'm sorry because I'm on my iphone and it's quite hard to read your code.
However there could be some problems:
1)you don't refresh the resizable element,may try to reinitalize the plugin function
2) you are trying to resize a duplicated id.
3) if you are adding to append something and you want to use a click function or similar you have to bind it with $(document).on(event,element,function(){})
**Brutal Solution**
Destroy and reinitalize the element

Comment: Thank you Dheed, But how draggable is working? i dint reinitialize the plugin.  can you help me out ?

Comment: $("#shirt").on("click", function(){ 
  $(this).resizable();

This is also not working
@Dheed

Comment: If it is the problem the ugliest solution is to call the destroy method and then reinitalize the element

Comment: The console doesn't say anything?

Comment: This should means that the browser/JavaScript doesn't recognize the element as part of the DOM (I'm not an expert,I'm just talking by experience). Have you tries the destroy/recall the plugin method?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25310/discussion-between-mahesh-vemuri-and-dheed)

Answer (score 0):

@Dheed Thanks for the solution. As you said , i have tried destroying it and reinitialized

```
$("#shirt").resizable("destroy"); 
  $("#shirt").resizable({
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: '#leftpanel'      // sets to can be dragged only within its parent
  });
```

This worked for me.

Thank you so much Dheed